# For a linear operator,T, show the existence of a polynomial, p, such that p(T) is a nilpotent operator

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I am faced with the following (homework) problem.

Given an operator $T : C^{n} \rightarrow C^{n}$, show that there exists a polynomial $p(z) \in C$ of degree at most $n - 1$ such that $p(T)$ is a nilpotent operator.

Unfortunately, I am unsure about how to approach this problem. Can anyone give me some clues?

Comment: Examine T as a product of its eigenvalues.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean @JakeColor. T will have $n$ eigenvalues, so a product of all of its eigenvalues will give me an $n$-degree polynomial. How will this help?

Comment: @Bidski:  nice question,, but don't you mean $p(z) \in C[z]$?

Comment: @RobertLewis: The way the question is worded is exactly how it was given to me. Although you are probably correct in saying $p(z) \in C[z]$ is what was intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not to put too fine a point on it, but except for trivialities, this cannot be the case as stated.  Counterexample:   consider the linear map $T:C^2 \to C^2$ such that

$T(z_1, z_2)^T = (\lambda_1 z_1, \lambda_2 z_2)^T, \tag{1}$

where $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \in C$, $\lambda_1 \ne \lambda_2$, and $\lambda_1 \ne 0 \ne \lambda_2$.  In matrix form, we have

$T = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2 \end{bmatrix}.\tag{2}$

Any polynomial  $p(z) \in C[z]$, $\deg p(z)) \le 1$,  may be written in the form $p(z) = az + b$ for $a,b \in C$; thus $p(T) = aT + b$.  Then, from (2),

$aT + b = \begin{bmatrix} a \lambda_1 + b & 0 \\ 0 & a \lambda_2 + b \end{bmatrix}. \tag{3}$

If $aT + b$ were nilpotent, then we would have $(aT + b)^n = 0$ for some ingeter $n \ge 2$.  Then (3) yields

$0 = (aT + b)^n = \begin{bmatrix} (a \lambda_1 + b)^n & 0 \\ 0 & (a \lambda_2 + b)^n \end{bmatrix}, \tag{3}$

forcing

$a \lambda_1 + b = a \lambda_2 + b = 0. \tag{4}$

Now if we allow $a = 0$, (4) becomes $b = 0$, so $aT + b = 0$, which is not nilpotent in any non-trivial sense.  If $a \ne 0$, then (4) forces $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2$, a contradiction.

This simple counterexample shows that such polynomials with $p(T)$ nilpotent cannot exist in general without further conditions on $T$.

I hope this helps sort things out.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: This makes a lot of sense to me, and I think I was slowly coming to this conclusion myself (although thinking that I must be wrong since we are never asked to show that something exists if it doesn't actually exist).

Comment: To Bidski:  well, there's always a first time!

Comment: To Bidski:  textbooks, handouts, lecture notes, etc. often have typos ans other errors.  I think as you grow mathematically,.you learn to sort these things out.

Comment: Thanks Robert Lewis, I shall let you know what the official solution was supposed to be.

Comment: To Robert Lewis: Turns out this question was asked wrong. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Bidski:  So what *is* the right question here?  The "Mathematician on the Street" wants to know!  And glad to be of service in this matter.

Comment: I have not had the chance to talk to my lecturer in depth about this yet, so the real question is currently unknown. I will post back once I know more.

Comment: Lecturer was trying to pull a fast one on us. This is the correct question and the intention was for us to find a counter-example.

Comment: To Bidski:  well, that we did!  Caught him red-handed, smoking gun!  +1 for the home team.  Cheers!--I can hear the bleachers roaring! ;)